# Can the spell elemental touch be used with the magus's spellstrike ability?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, spells, class-feature

So I learned that spellstrike can be used with a held charge for use of abilities like spring attack. So you can cast shocking grasp one round and then use spring attack and expend the shocking grasp spell the next.

What i wanted to know is does the spell elemental touch work on the same principal?

This is the spell here.

*Upon completing the casting of this spell, elemental energy infuses      your hands.*

*Choose an energy type: acid, cold, electricity, or fire.     You gain a    melee touch attack causing 1d6 points of damage of that    energy type,    along with a special effect described below. You also    deal energy    damage and the related special effect when you attack     with your hands    using an unarmed strike, a single claw, or a       single slam attack. This    bonus damage can never apply to multiple     weapons.*

- Acid: Your touch    attack causes 1 point of ongoing acid
  damage per round for 1 round    per three caster levels. The target
  must make a Fortitude save or be    sickened for the duration of the 
  ongoing acid damage.
- Cold: The    target must make a Fortitude save      or be fatigued. A
  creature that is    already fatigued suffers no       additional
  effect.
- Electricity: The    target must make a Fortitude      save or    be
  staggered for 1 round.
- Fire:    Your hands ignite and shed    light as a torch. Your touch
  may cause    targets to catch on fire.

  *Subsequent attacks inflict the normal    damage, but the additional      effects do not stack. This spell grants no    special protection to      anything held in or worn on your hands. When    you cast this spell      to deal acid, cold, electricity, or fire damage,    it is a spell of     that type.*

Answer (score 5):

### No, self-targeting spells cannot be used with Spellstrike.

The magus's [Spellstrike](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/ultimateMagic/spellcasters/magus.html) ability enables them to cast touch-range spells through their weapon.

> At 2nd level, whenever a magus casts a spell with a range of “touch” from the magus spell list, he can deliver the spell through any weapon he is wielding as part of a melee attack.

There are several [magus arcana](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/classes/base-classes/magus/magus-arcana/) options available that expand what you can do with Spellstrike, but none of them enable you to cast spells with a range of self.

Although [*Elemental Touch*](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic/all-spells/e/elemental-touch/) does give you a touch attack, the spell itself is not a touch-range spell. It has a range of "personal", and the target is "you". There is no charge to hold. On subsequent rounds while *Elemental Touch* is active, you use can make the touch attack provided by the spell, however this attack is not the same as casting the spell.

Therefore it is not usable with Spellstrike.